# sklearn MinMaxScaler mis-scaling?

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm having trouble understanding one of the scaled columns in a pandas dataframe returned by MinMaxScaler:

The code snippet is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

A = np.random.randint(5, size=(8, 4))
FrameA = pd.DataFrame()
FrameA = A

scaled_array = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(FrameA)
```

Scaled (LHS) and original (RHS)

[image: Scaled (LHS) and original (RHS)]

Column 2 is suspect. The formula seems to be: x[i] / max{x} - 1 which differs from the other columns.

Comment: Apologies everyone. I'm a moron. The formula is actually (x[i] - min{x}) / (max{x} - min{x}). All good.